# Recaptcha with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, recaptcha

Unfortunately I dont get Recaptcha working for my application on `localhost`. I followed the introduction on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-captcha). I created a website key and secret for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

[image]

In my html head there is the script src:

```
 `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`
```

And the div for the recaptcha looks like:

```
`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le_LZgUAAAAAKlzsoEBOOQvCOqIr7r65eiN4bd4">recaptcha</div>`
`<span id="captchaError" class="alert alert-danger " style="display:none"></span>`
```

But I always get an error aout invalid website key:

[image]

What can I do? Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution i came across is using the `recaptcha-spring-boot-starter`. It reduces my code heavily, but I got it run with Recaptcha V2 only. But thats also okay for me:

https://github.com/mkopylec/recaptcha-spring-boot-starter-samples

Answer (score 1):

I got it work and it works also on localhost. First of all if you create a new API key I guess it could take few times that is has been really activated.

On my page I did now following:

```
`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Le_LZgUAAAAAM5uw_9hujkS6SjBWLNVkQOvewWf'></script>`
```

And I removed the `<div class="g-recaptcha" ...` (see question) completly.

API is still registered for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`

No I have something like:

[image]

Comment: my bad, i shud have researched thoroughly and yes good job finding solution. it seems working now. i think you are using v3 of recaptcha, if you are expecting the checkbox than you have to use v2.

Comment: and plz do not share your private key or even public key in question. they are supposed for your use only and shud be kept secret.

Comment: Hi Galzor, thanks for your reply. The Keys will be exchanged later, currently they are just used for locally. But thanks for the hint. :-)

Comment: and yes I am using V3